# Dotnet.highcharts packages issues with using

Tags: .net, highcharts

I have added the nuget package for the Dotnet.Highchart, and in bin folder i specifically copy the dll of Dotnet.highchart but still i am getting the error of The type or namespace name 'DotNet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).
is their any other setting need to be fixed to run this.

Comment: *How* have you "added the nuget package"? You shouldn't need to manually copy the dll at all. If you add the NuGet package to the project, you should see the package in your project references...

Comment: ok, but still i am facing the same error. my target framework is .net 4.0 which i am using with that.

Comment: Well does the reference show in your project references?

Comment: Yes.It shows the reference

Comment: Can you copy and paste your exact `using` directive? You've specified "Dotnet" twice in your question, and "DotNet" once - they're not the same...

Comment: I have got the solutions for this, if i use the .net framework 4.5 it will support the highcharts libraray .net 4.0 showing the problem with that.